# RabbitMQ truncates to 50,000 bytes when viewed?

Tags: rabbitmq

I am considering going to RabbitMQ from MSMQ.

I was playing around it with and wanted to see the messages in the queue (usually easy with MSMQ).

It is a bit harder with RabbitMQ, but I made it work.  But the help text says:

> Furthermore, message payloads will be truncated to 50000 bytes.

That is less that 0.05 MB!  My payloads are much much larger than that.

So here is my question, **does it truncate just for viewing, or for the message that is put back in the queue too?**

**Also, can this limit be configured?**  When debugging, I would frequently need to see the full message.

Comment: Can you link to where you've read this... also take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18353898/rabbitmq-message-size-and-types and http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.networking.rabbitmq.general/14665,

Comment: also this http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2012/04/25/rabbitmq-performance-measurements-part-2/

Comment: @kzhen - It was in the queue page for the Management Pugin for RabbitMQ (http://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html).  If click on the ? next to the Warning under Get messages.

Comment: Use the Rest API, and specify a large 'truncate' value https://stackoverflow.com/a/38390174/1181624

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is only truncated when you view it (due to UI limitations; the assumption probably is that if the message is larger than 50k, then it is binary). The message with the same payload will be re-queued.

As for "peeking" into queues: I had the same problem, I wanted to check out what is flowing through the queues on our brokers. In the end I wrote a few tools to be able to do it from the command line. I usually create a temporary queue, bind it to the same exchange as the original one via the same routing key, and dump a few messages to disk.