# Install rabbitmqadmin on linux

Tags: linux, rabbitmq, rabbitmqadmin

I'm trying to install and be able to run rabbitmqadmin on a linux machine. Following the instructions described [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management-cli.html) do not help.

After downloading the file linked, it prompts to copy the file (which looks like a python script) into `/usr/local/bin`.

Trying to run it by simply invoking `rabbitmqadmin` results in `rabbitmqadmin: command not found`. There seems to be no information anywhere about how to get this to work and assumes that all the steps listed on the site should work for all. It seems odd that simply copying a python script to the `bin` folder should allow it to become a recognised command without having to invoke the python interpreter every time.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That should work fine unless, for some strange reason, `/usr/local/bin` is not specified on your `$PATH`.

Comment: "without having to invoke the python interpreter" — see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)

Comment: `/usr/local/bin` is indeed specified on my `$PATH`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

RabbitMQ decided to omit one vital piece of information.

Make the script executable with `chmod +x` otherwise it will fail to work.

Answer (score 23):

I spent several hours to figure out this, use rabbitmqadmin on linux environment, Finally below steps solve my issue.

On my ubuntu server, python3 was installed, I checked it using below command,

```
python3 -V
```

Step 1: download the python script to your linux server

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/v3.7.8/bin/rabbitmqadmin
```

Step2: change the permission

```
chmod 777 rabbitmqadmin
```

Step3: change the header of the script as below(first line)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

Thant's all, Now you can run below commands,

To list down queues,

```
./rabbitmqadmin -f tsv -q list queues
```

To Delete ques,

```
./rabbitmqadmin delete queue name=name_of_queue
```

To add binding between exchange and queue

```
./rabbitmqadmin declare binding source="exchangename" destination_type="queue" destination="queuename" routing_key="routingkey"
```

Comment: This helped, however I disagree with the chmod 777 and agree with @Shiri in regard to the only adding of the execute permissions.  I would further that to only the user/group of that will be running the commands as well.

Answer (score 9):

I want to post my commands for installing rabbitmqadmin, it is combination of other answers, but with a little improvements for using best practice:

```
sudo rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
wget 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/v3.7.15/bin/rabbitmqadmin'
chmod +x rabbitmqadmin
sed -i 's|#!/usr/bin/env python|#!/usr/bin/env python3|' rabbitmqadmin
mv rabbitmqadmin .local/bin/
rabbitmqadmin -q list queues
```

I suppose that you already create .local/bin/ dir and add it to PATH (on Ubuntu bash add this dir to PATH if it exists).

Answer (score 4):

After install Rabbbitmq on [Ubuntu/Debian](https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html), you can activate the Rabbitmq Admin Portal using the next command:

```
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

Then you can access to the portal from http://localhost:15672. Use the user/password "guest".

Answer (score 4):

Below the steps to install rabbimqadmin:

```
cd /usr/local/bin/
wget http://127.0.0.1:15672/cli/rabbitmqadmin
chmod 777 rabbitmqadmin
```

For more details check the official documentation [Obtaining rabbitmqadmin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management-cli.html)