# Discarding rabbitmq messages no one is listening to

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I am a complete newbie to rabbitmq messaging, apologies if this question is silly or my setup completely pear-shaped.

My setup where I use rabbitmq is sending messages from certain probes. Each probe has a unique name. I have then a centralised server where I process the data - if there is a need.

I use a direct exchange and routing keys that correspond to probe names.

I declare my consumer (server) as follows (this is more or less from rabbitmq tutorials):

```
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()
channel.exchange_declare(exchange="foo", type="direct")
result = channel.queue_declare(exclusive=True)
queue_name = result.method.queue
```

If at some point I become interested in what a probe is reporting, I issue

```
channel.queue_bind(exchange="foo", queue=queue_name, routing_key="XXX")
```

where XXX is the name of the probe.

My publishers at the probes are declared as follows:

```
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host="foo.bar.com"))
channel = connection.channel()
channel.exchange_declare(exchange="foo", type="direct")
```

and when I send a message, I use

```
channel.basic_publish(exchange="foo", routing_key="XXX", body=data)
```

where XXX is the name of the probe.

This all works fine. But how do I make it so that messages to routing keys that no one is listening to get discarded immediately? Now if my consumer stops listening to a routing key or is not running at all, messages sent by probes start piling up. When I start my consumer or have it listen to a routing key is has not been listening to in a while, I might have tens of thousands of messages backlog there. This is not what I need, and that backlog is bound to cause a resource exhaustion somewhere.

Is there a way to modify this so that messages get discarded instead of queued if there is no one listening to them when they arrive at the exchange? I would assume there is a way but Google and pika documents did not help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But how do I make it so that messages to routing keys that no one is
>   listening to get discarded immediately?

By default, Rabbitmq has implemented this.You just need to make sure that there is no queue which is binded to that routing key.

> Now if my consumer stops listening to a routing key or is not running
>   at all, messages sent by probes start piling up

If there is no queue for that routing key, all messages will be discarded.

> Is there a way to modify this so that messages get discarded instead
>   of queued if there is no one listening to them when they arrive at the
>   exchange?

Rabbitmq defualt behavior itself support this(for Direct Exchange)

Go through page at https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-four-python.html

Comment: Ok, so as long as I close the listening queue, messages should be discarded.  I will accept this as an answer.  Is there a way with rabbitmqctl to check if there are queued messages there, to verify it works?

Comment: To see queued messages you can use rabbitmq management plugin.More details at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10709533/is-it-possible-to-view-rabbitmq-message-contents-directly-from-the-command-line