# How to consume RabbitMQ messages using a terminal or tool?

Tags: java, windows, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-rabbit

I have the following `rabbitmq` configuration in a Spring Boot microservice:

***application.yml:***

```
rabbitmq:
  addresses: app-test.company.com:5671
  vhost: app-test
  username: user
  password: ******
  queueName: c.app.dev.demo.masterdata100int
  exchangeName: e.app.masterdata100int
```

I want to check some specific messages on the queue and for this purpose, have tried several tools e.g. `Queue Explorer`, `Qu Desktop` and `Command Line`, but could not connect and consume messages properly. I get the following errors when trying to connect using `Queue Explorer`:

***with TLS option:***

> Could not load machine overview: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.

***without TLS option:***

> Could not load machine overview: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.

But the username and password used to connect are correct and I would also try using some other tool in case I miss some configuration settings. Do you have any suggestion to consume a RabbitMQ messages on a remote server?

**Note:** The commands or the tools should work on Windows as I use Windows 10.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to view RabbitMQ message contents directly from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10709533/is-it-possible-to-view-rabbitmq-message-contents-directly-from-the-command-line)

Comment: @experimentunit1998X Had already tried workarounds on that page before opening the question, but not worked.